# installing reportLab in python django service ubuntu

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu

in python django service to generate pdf report tried to install reportLab in env

```
pip install ReportLab
```

shows error pillow ,i think some dependency of reportLab throw error

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pip>=1.4.1 

in /home/phoenix/djenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ReportLab)
Collecting pillow>=2.4.0 (from ReportLab)
  Using cached Pillow-3.0.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=2.2 in /home/phoenix/djenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ReportLab)
Installing collected packages: pillow, ReportLab
  Running setup.py install for pillow
    Complete output from command /home/phoenix/djenv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-0ocjqD/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dAEFWI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/phoenix/djenv/include/site/python2.7/pillow:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying PIL/OleFileIO-README.md -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-0ocjqD/pillow/setup.py", line 767, in <module>
        zip_safe=not debug_build(),
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/phoenix/djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 601, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 337, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-0ocjqD/pillow/setup.py", line 515, in build_extensions
        % (f, f))
    ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/phoenix/djenv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-0ocjqD/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dAEFWI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/phoenix/djenv/include/site/python2.7/pillow" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0ocjqD/pillow
```

ended up like this

also tried some solution like adding this flags

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Comment: tried installing pillow separately  pip install pillow==2.4.0
ends up like 

 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’

    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’

    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: dont mention the version number in that, just do pip install pillow

Comment: try installing python-dev, libevent-dev.  `sudo apt-get install python-dev libevent-dev`. Then try to to install pillow again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Reportlab python package index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab)

### 2.1 General prerequisites

You need to have installed Python (versions 2.7 or >=3.3), 
and ideally PIL or Pillow with Freetype support;

Try

```
pip install pillow
```

and retry installing reportlab

EDIT:

For your mentioned error, try installing common dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: python --version
Python 2.7.9

Comment: Thats fine Arun, just try installing doing pip install pillow and then pip install ReportLab.

Comment: already tried  'pip install pillow'           "    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’  "
 "   x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’  "
"    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1  "

Comment: previous error gone  "  ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.
 "

Comment: Have you successfully installed reportlab? when and for what you got this error?

Comment: pip freeze don't show report labs  pip install pillow showed this error fixed it now by installing libjpeg-dev  "sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev "

Comment: ValueError: --enable-zlib requested but zlib not found, aborting.

Comment: Keep installing packages for which it is showing not found error

Comment: Glad that I could help, please tick answer as correct if it helped